# parse a netscape-style bookmarks html file into nested array

Tags: multidimensional-array, html-parsing, bookmarks

I'm trying to build a service that could parse a netscape-style bookmarks html export file and return a multi-dimensional array where folders and bookmarks are nested, as they where in the file.

I found some libraries, but none of them are keeping the folders and bookmarsk nested, or if they do, they do not return an array, they are echo'ing the line 1 by 1 in the loop and indent them accordingly.

This is what a nescape-style bookmarks export looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<!-- This is an automatically generated file.
     It will be read and overwritten.
     DO NOT EDIT! -->
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Menu des marque-pages</H1>

<DL><p>
    <DT><A HREF="place:folder=BOOKMARKS_MENU&folder=UNFILED_BOOKMARKS&folder=TOOLBAR&queryType=1&sort=12&maxResults=10&excludeQueries=1" ADD_DATE="1422119261" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119261">Marqués récemment</A>
    <DT><A HREF="place:type=6&sort=14&maxResults=10" ADD_DATE="1422119261" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119261">Étiquettes récentes</A>
    <HR>    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1422119260" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119260">Mozilla Firefox</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><A HREF="https://www.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/help/" ADD_DATE="1422119260" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119260" ICON_URI="http://www.mozilla.org/2005/made-up-favicon/0-1422119260996" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Aide et didacticiels</A>
        <DT><A HREF="https://www.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/customize/" ADD_DATE="1422119260" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119260" ICON_URI="http://www.mozilla.org/2005/made-up-favicon/1-1422119260997" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Personnaliser Firefox</A>
        <DT><A HREF="https://www.mozilla.org/fr/contribute/" ADD_DATE="1422119260" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119260" ICON_URI="http://www.mozilla.org/2005/made-up-favicon/2-1422119260998" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">Contribuer</A>
        <DT><A HREF="https://www.mozilla.org/fr/about/" ADD_DATE="1422119260" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119260" ICON_URI="http://www.mozilla.org/2005/made-up-favicon/3-1422119260999" ICON="data:image/png;base64,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">À propos de Mozilla</A>
    </DL><p>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1422119260" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119261" PERSONAL_TOOLBAR_FOLDER="true">Barre personnelle</H3>
    <DD>Ajoutez des marque-pages dans ce dossier pour les voir apparaître sur votre barre personnelle
    <DL><p>
        <DT><A HREF="place:sort=8&maxResults=10" ADD_DATE="1422119261" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119261">Les plus visités</A>
        <DT><A HREF="https://www.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/central/" ADD_DATE="1422119260" LAST_MODIFIED="1422119260">Débuter avec Firefox</A>
    </DL><p>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1422119260" LAST_MODIFIED="1466788235" UNFILED_BOOKMARKS_FOLDER="true">Marque-pages non classés</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1466788235" LAST_MODIFIED="1466788267">Veille</H3>
        <DL><p>
            <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1466788242" LAST_MODIFIED="1466788267">PHP</H3>
            <DL><p>
                <DT><A HREF="http://php.net/" ADD_DATE="1466788255" LAST_MODIFIED="1466788255" ICON_URI="http://php.net/favicon.ico" ICON="data:image/png;base64,Qk02AwAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAEAAAABAAAAABABgAAAAAAAADAADEDgAAxA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICA19fX19fX19fXwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICA19fX19fX19fXwICAwICAwICA19fXAAAA19fXwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICA19fXAAAA19fXwICAwICAwICA19fXAAAA19fX19fXwICAwICA19fXwICAwICA19fX19fXAAAA19fX19fXwICAwICA19fXAAAAAAAAAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fXAAAAAAAAAAAA19fX19fX19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAA19fX19fXAAAAAAAAAAAA19fX19fXAAAAAAAAAAAA19fX19fXAAAAAAAAAAAA19fX19fXwICA19fX19fX19fXwICA19fXAAAA19fX19fXwICAwICA19fX19fX19fXwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICA19fXAAAA19fXwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICA19fX19fX19fXwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICAwICA" LAST_CHARSET="UTF-8">PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor</A>
                <DD>
            </DL><p>
        </DL><p>
    </DL><p>
</DL>
```

`<H3>` are folders, `<a>` are bookmarks

I have no idea how to start. I probably should use some recursive function ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small command-line utility named [Nebooman](https://github.com/Zebradil/nebooman) that can clean up bookmarks. It reads from Netscape Bookmark Format file and generates valid Netscape Bookmark Format file.
It written in python3. The main class reads bookmarks from file into nested structure. So you can use parts of its source code or [create future request](https://github.com/Zebradil/nebooman/issues/new) for improving utility api.

Your code may looks like:

```python
from nebooman import Manager
import json

manager = Manager(verbose=True)
manager.read_bookmarks_file(open('bookmarks.html'))
print(json.dump(manager.bookmarks))
```